# How to get matrix 1D from Wavelet DWT using Opencv?

Tags: python, opencv, wavelet, haar-wavelet, dwt

I've tried to use haar wavelet method but the result matrix is not in 1D matrix. How to get 1D matrix from haar wavelet?
Here's my code:

```
Import cv2
From pwt import wavedec

imgcv1 = cv2.split(resize)[0] cv2.boxFilter(imgcv1, 0, (7,7), imgcv1, (-1,-1), False, cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT) #cv2.resize( imgcv1, (32, 32 ) ,imgcv1) 
imf = np.float32(imgcv1)/255.0 
# float conversion/scale
coeffs = wavedec(imf, "haar", level = 2)
cA2 = coeff
print(cA2)
```

Comment: Duplicated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72919085/calculate-discrete-wavelet-haar-transform-of-image-with-opencv

Comment: code is misformatted. [edit] your question and fix it. please review [mre].